# Generic Job Scheduler and Executor framework

Tags: architecture, frameworks, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I need to design a generic job scheduler & executor framework. This framework will define interfaces for executing the jobs on a remote computer, or scheduling the jobs based on external triggers/schedule/duration etc.

Multiple applications will use this framework to schedule/execute jobs through multiple kinds of schedulers and executors (schedulers and executors will implement the interfaces defined by the framework). It's also desirable to be able to change the scheduler and executors tied to an application at the run time through configuration only.

Are there any such implementations/frameworks that I can refer to. I would like to understand their design and gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

you could check infinispan and hazelcast. both contain APIs to distribute tasks over multiple nodes.